# What should be included in the equilibrium constant expression?

Tags: organic-chemistry, equilibrium

Some writes that pure solids and pure liquids and also solvent should not appear in the Kc, yet a book writes that an carbonyl compound, insoluble in the water, the Kc for this reaction finally includes the water as the density of water is not a constant according to the notes.

Can anyone explain to me about this and what should be included into the Kc expression? And are there any special case for me to memorise in the exam?